# Duvida com LocalStorage -

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Tenho esse código que está contando a quantidade de Clicks, só que queria que quando fechar o Browser o contador não zere.

```js
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  document.body.appendChild(p);

  $(document).ready(function(){
      var cout = 0;   
      $("#btnCount").click(function(){
          cout = cout+1;
          $('p').html(cout);
      });
  });
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="btnCount">Click me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para salvar antes de fechar a página

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(count) {
    localStorage.setItem('count', count);
}
```

Como recuperar do localstorage

```
var count = localStorage.getItem('count');
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário armazenar o localStorage quando sair da página ou do navegador. Basta criar/atualizar ele dentro do evento onde são contados os cliques, e a variável `cout` deve ter um operador `||` para ter um de dois valores: `0` ou o do `localStorage` caso ele exista.

Outra coisa, você pode criar o `<p>` com jQuery mesmo, conforme sugiro abaixo:

```
$("body").append("</p>");
$(document).ready(function(){
   var cout = localStorage.getItem("cout") || 0;

   $("#btnCount").click(function(){
       cout = parseInt(cout)+1;
       $('p').html(cout);
       localStorage.setItem("cout", cout);
   });
});
```

> Outra coisa é que é preciso converter o valor de `cout` para *int* com
>   `parseInt()` porque o localStorage é em formato de string.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `setItem` do localStorage para guardar sua variável contador, ela possui a seguinte sintaxe

```
localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
```

Você pode acrescentar no seu código o seguinte para salvar em localStorage quando o browser for fechado.

**Exemplo**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(count) {
   localStorage.setItem('count', count);
}
```

**Recuperar o dado**

Para recuperar o dado igualmente possuímos a funca `getItem`

```
var count = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('count'));
```